# Inspect Genric Type

Tags: vb.net, generics

How can I test whether or not a type of a generic class implements a specific interface?

sample:

```
    Public Interface IBaseItemInterface(of Type)
    ...
    End Interface

    Public Interface ISpecificItemInterface(Of Type)
        Inherits IBaseItemInterface(of Type)
    ...
    End Interface

    Public Interface IRootInterface(of Type, TEntity as IBaseItemInterface))
    ...
    End Interface

    'Implementation
    Public Class Sample(of Type, TEntity as IBaseItemInterface))
        Implements IRootInterface(of Type, TEntity)

       Public Sub test()
           **If TEntity Implements ISpecificItemInterface then**
              DoSomethingSpecific
           End if
       End Sub 
    End Class
```

How can this be done? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use...

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim type = GetType(TEntity)
    Dim isMySpecificInterface = type.IsGenericType AndAlso 
          type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() Is GetType(ISpecificItemInterface(Of))

   If isMySpecificInterface then
        ' DoSomethingSpecific
   End if
End Sub
```